# Integration with cylindrical coordinates: Should I split the integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> I have $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2$ and $D=\{(x,y,z): (x,y,z) \text{ are points inside } x^2+y^2=2x \text{ and between} z=0,z=2\}$

The equation $x^2+y^2=2x$ is equivalent to $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ which determine that the points will be inside a circle with center $(1,0)$ and radius 1, with the condition $z=0$ and $z=2$ seems that $D$ is a cylinder.

Changing to cylindrical coordinates $x=\rho\cos\theta,y=\rho\sin\theta,z=z$.
Using $x^2+y^2=2x$ the change of coordinates implies that $\rho^2\cos^2\theta+\rho^2\sin^2\theta=2\rho\cos\theta \implies \rho = 2\cos\theta$.

Then $$0\leq \rho\leq 2\cos\theta\\0\leq z \leq 2$$

Usually I would choose $-\pi/2\leq\theta\leq\pi/2$ and that's where my problem because book says that the $\theta$ in the change of coords must satisfy $0\leq\theta \leq 2\pi$, this means that for $D$ I'd have $0\leq\theta\leq\pi /2$ and $3/2\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$.

Does this means that I should split the integral and have $\displaystyle\iiint_Df(x,y,z) = \int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}\rho^3\;d\rho d\theta dz+\int_0^1\int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}\rho^3\;d\rho d\theta dz$ ?.

Is okay if I proceed this way?

Comment: I suppose it's okay (it's not really ideal), but you can get the same region if you instead consider the bounds $0\leq \theta\leq \pi$.  Thus, the integral you would want to evaluate would be $$\int_0^2\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}\rho^3\,d\rho\,d\theta\,dz$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see below, the limit for $\theta$ is $[0,\pi]$. Any other limits for it are wrong:

[image]

Here $3\pi/2$ can be interpreted as $\theta=0$ and $\pi/2$ as $\pi$

Comment: Thanks a lot @B.S, I think I got it. With what I did before since $\cos$ takes positive values at both $[0,\pi/2]$ and $[3\pi/4,2\pi]$ I would be going through the upper half of the circle twice, right?.

Comment: @Dante: Seems right.